# Most mathematically rigorous books to learn statistics from?

Tags: references

Assume the math background is not an issue. Which books would you recommend as the most mathematically rigorous to learn mathematical statistics at the graduate level?

Does *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics* (3 volumes) fit the bill?  Or is Schervish's *Theory of Statistics* better in this aspect? Or some other book?

Doesn't need to be in one book. I'm just doing this as a challenge of some sort. I have time.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rigorous+statistics+%5Breferences%5D

Comment: There was a long history in major statistical journals of sharp reviews of successive editions of the Kendall series (latterly revised by Stuart, Ord and Arnold, but of those four only Keith Ord survives and the series appears stalled) as being less than rigorous. It has other virtues, but rigour is not its main claim to attention. Wasserman's books are a nice compromise between clarity and rigour.

Answer (score 3):

The core of mathematical statistics is point estimation and hypothesis testing. From a frequentist perspective, my votes go to *Theory of Point Estimation* by Lehmann and Casella, and *Testing Statistical Hypotheses* by Lehmann and Romano.

Answer (score 1):

What area of Statistics do you want to learn? For example, if you are willing to consider Machine Learning as a branch of statistics, then *Murphy (2012): Machine learning: a probabilistic perspective* is a good option.

Comment: I'm looking at all the standard stuff in a graduate course on mathematical statistics: distributions, inference, regression, multivariate stuff etc. Doesn't need to be in one book. I'm just doing this as a challenge of some sort. I have time.

Comment: Murphy is a good book, but I don't know that I would call it "the most mathematically rigorous" or being about "mathematical statistics." A much more mathematical ML book would be e.g. [Foundations of Machine Learning](https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/) by Mohri, Rostamizadeh, and Talwalkar.

Comment: @Dougal thank you for the comment, I myself learned something new